# Click on navigation does not open the activity

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm working on bottom navigation. The problem is that, when I click on one icon on the navigation bar, it is open the activity I want but the icon is appeared it doesn't clicked it just by default the first icon appear as it clicked all the time

```
public class MainActivity 
        extends AppCompatActivity 
        implements 
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

      BottomNavigationView nav;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

    nav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    } //  ------------------end of on create--------------------


      @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

         switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.prof:

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
            profile.class);
            menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.profile);
            nav.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
            startActivity(intent);


            break;


        case R.id.hm:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
            MainActivity.class);
            nav.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
            startActivity(intent1);


            break;


        case R.id.consult:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, tabs.class);
            nav.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
            startActivity(intent3);

            break;


        case R.id.dash:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
            Dashboard.class);
            nav.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
            startActivity(intent2);

            break;


    }
    return false;
}

}
```

my main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/purple"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

my navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/hm"
    android:icon="@drawable/hom"
    android:enabled="true"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    tools:ignore="MenuTitle" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/prof"
    android:icon="@drawable/profile"
    android:enabled="true"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    tools:ignore="MenuTitle" />

 <item
    android:id="@+id/consult"
    android:icon="@drawable/consult"
    android:enabled="true"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    tools:ignore="MenuTitle" />
    <item
    android:id="@+id/dash"
    android:icon="@drawable/dashboard"
    android:enabled="true"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    tools:ignore="MenuTitle" />
  </menu>
```

this my nav_item_color_state.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@android:color/white" 
 android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" 
 android:state_enabled="false"/>

</selector>
```

this my interface in all my activity
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC5o5.png)
please help me  I update the question

Comment: Put this code in your onCreate  after initilizing the nav object nav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: is open but the icon title does not appear

Comment: I mean, the code in `R.id.consult` is commented out. That may be the cause of your problems?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it won't even enter that method, to begin with.

Comment: I remove the consult comment but it still does not appear as it clicked

Answer (score 1):

You don't bind any `onNavigationItemSelected()` listener there; for example:

```
nav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
nav.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: the setNavigationItemSelectedListener is appear with error

Comment: @noraKhaled what do you mean by "appear with error"? it reads `implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, therefore I'd assume that it should be known. `R.id.navigation` might be the wrong resId, and that error might be a `NullPointerException`. Can that be?

Comment: thanks for your answer but still does not appear the icon as clicked

Comment: @noraKhaled please add the layout XML to the question. you might be referring to `resId` in some other view...instead of the ones in the `BottomNavigationView`. just add logging to the code to see what what happens.

Comment: I add the all layout I use